# jQuery datepicker localization not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker, child-theming

To use the jQuery `datepicker` I have these scripts loaded for my Wordpress blog site:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery-ui-css-css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css?ver=4.7.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js?ver=4.7.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js?ver=4.7.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js?ver=4.7.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mywebaddress.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/wpadverts/js/datepicker-ro.js?ver=4.7.3'></script>
```

and I have this piece of code for localized `datepicker`:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $('#adverts_eventDate').datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional['ro'], {
            showButtonPanel : true,
            dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
        }));
        } );
</script>
```

This code works, so I have a date picker, but it is not localized (for Romanian), it is in English. What is wrong with my code?

This is how those scripts are enqueued in my Wordpress child theme:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wpadverts_plugin_custom_styles' ) ):
   function wpadverts_plugin_custom_styles() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-min-js', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-css', 'http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-js', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js' );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-i18n-min', 'http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js' );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker-ro', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/wpadverts/js/datepicker-ro.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
   }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpadverts_plugin_custom_styles' );
```

**UPDATE**

Now my localized datepicker looks like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['ro'] = {
        closeText: 'Închide',
        prevText: '&laquo; Luna precedentă',
        nextText: 'Luna următoare &raquo;',
        currentText: 'Azi',
        monthNames: ['Ianuarie','Februarie','Martie','Aprilie','Mai','Iunie',
    'Iulie','August','Septembrie','Octombrie','Noiembrie','Decembrie'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ian', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Iun',
    'Iul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        dayNames: ['Duminică', 'Luni', 'Marţi', 'Miercuri', 'Joi', 'Vineri', 'Sâmbătă'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dum', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Joi', 'Vin', 'Sâm'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Du','Lu','Ma','Mi','Jo','Vi','Sâ'],
        weekHeader: 'Săpt',
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ro']);
});

$( '#adverts_eventDate' ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional['ro'] );

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this and try

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/kadgzfhx/)

using your JS

```
 $(function() {
   $('#adverts_eventDate').datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional['ro'], {
     showButtonPanel: true,
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
   }));
 });
```

Comment: The missing/wrong part of my code was the correct link of *jquery-ui-i18n.min.js*. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below , example how you can do localization by yourself.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['ro'] = {
        closeText: 'Închide',
        prevText: '&laquo; Luna precedentă',
        nextText: 'Luna următoare &raquo;',
        currentText: 'Azi',
        monthNames: ['Ianuarie','Februarie','Martie','Aprilie','Mai','Iunie',
    'Iulie','August','Septembrie','Octombrie','Noiembrie','Decembrie'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ian', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Iun',
    'Iul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        dayNames: ['Duminică', 'Luni', 'Marţi', 'Miercuri', 'Joi', 'Vineri', 'Sâmbătă'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dum', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Joi', 'Vin', 'Sâm'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Du','Lu','Ma','Mi','Jo','Vi','Sâ'],
        weekHeader: 'Săpt',
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ro']);
});
```

Comment: I tried `$( '#adverts_eventDate' ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional['ro'] );` and also `$( '#adverts_eventDate' ).datepicker();` but date picker still is in English. I updated my question.

Comment: The missing/wrong part of my code was the correct link of *jquery-ui-i18n.min.js*. Thank you!